# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I was doing Facial Expression Recognition on kaggle kernel and everything was going smooth, but suddenly the following code started giving error.

> import tensorflow as tf
>
> x = tf.placeholder(shape = [None, image_pixels], dtype = tf.float32)
> y = tf.placeholder(shape = [None, labels_count], dtype = tf.float32)
>
> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'

I have tried many alternatives available on internet such as using

> import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
>
> tf.disable_v2_behavior()

this instead of

> import tensorflow as tf

But all went in vain. Kindly help me out here

Answer (score 3):

change the <`tf.placeholder`> as <`tf.compat.v1.placeholder`>

such as

```
x = tf.placeholder(shape = [None, image_pixels], dtype = tf.float32)
```

change as

```
x = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(shape = [None, image_pixels], dtype = tf.float32)
```

but there would be another problem about runtime error with eager execution
add <tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()> after import part

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

like this